# Is it true that $ a_k:= \sum_{n=1}^{k} \text{sgn}(\sin(n)) $ only takes values from $ \{ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 \},\ $ and if so, how do we prove it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, problem-solving

Here, $\ \text{sgn}\ $ means the [sign a.k.a signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) function, and the angle units are in radians.

Based on experimentation (the Python code at the bottom), it seems that each member of the sequence $\ (a_k)_k\ $ defined by:

$$ a_k:= \sum_{n=1}^{k} \text{sgn}(\sin(n)) $$

only takes values from the set $ \{ -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 \}. $

> Is this true? And how can this be proven?

I know that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } \sin n\ $ is bounded, but I don't see how this helps. I also don't know about any of the equidistribution properties of the sequence $\ (\sin n)_n\ $ but I don't think this matters, as I doubt this would be useful because those things are asymptotic properties, not absolute properties.

But maybe I a overlooking something simple to answer my original question: however, I don't see it (obviously...). Here is my code:

```
import math

sineList=[]

for i in range(1000):
    if math.sin(i)>0:
        sineList.append(1)
    elif math.sin(i)==0:
        sineList.append(0)
    else:
        sineList.append(-1)
    print(sum(sineList))
```

Comment: Is it implicitly said that $n$ is in radians, not in degrees...

Comment: @JeanMarie I've added that in, but yes we're working in radians...

Comment: $\sin$ changes its signal when the argument is increased by $\pi$ and $3 \leq \pi \leq 4$, so the maximum number of ones you can sum is 3

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta according to the duplicate, $(a_k)_k$ is unbounded.

Comment: @RaulFernandesHorta I'm not sure I understand your comment. AnneBauval that's certainly closely related, although I'm not sure it answers my question directly. Although it shows that my question is harder than I first thought...

Comment: Oh, the link says it is *unbounded*. Wow... it's very slow at diverging then!

Comment: @AnneBauval I realized that what I was thinking  was wrong, thanks, I thought that the sum would eventually cancel, but actually that is not true according to the duplicate because the period is irrational.